# Help to check a String pattern/format

Tags: apex, string

I need to check  a string using apex whether it is in the following format:

1. Anything-Insert-Anything-True
2. Anything-Update-Anything-True
3. Anything-Delete-Anything-False

Anything(it can be any string).
The last one may be true or false.

How to check it using apex? need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Boolean isMatched =
Pattern.matches('(.*-Insert-.*-)(True|False)','abc-Insert-def-True');
System.debug('Result : '+isMatched);

if(isMatched){
//goes here }
```

- is shifted to correct place

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.it is quite close. Just one thing, i can have insert or update or delete.For that what i need to do.

Comment: Hey, it's another one. I just answered for what you have asked ;) Try this
`Pattern.matches('(.-*(Insert|Update|Delete)-.*-)(True|False)','abc-Insert-def-True');`

Comment: Have u tried the above? its returning false when I am passing this value: abc-Insert-def-True

Comment: Check your matcher. It's having '-' at the end which will not match with the pattern. The only difference of my two answers is second one accepting Insert or Update or Delete

Comment: When i run this in console-> Boolean isMatched = Pattern.matches('(.-*Insert-.*-)(True|False)','abc-Insert-def-True'); It returns false. please check
System.debug('Result : '+isMatched);

Comment: Check the pattern again with the answer, I think you have missed '*' mark after each '.' marck, which need to accept multiple chars

Comment: While copy pasting in the comment the * was missing but I ran exactly same code that you gave in the console with * and all. Still it is returning false :( :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13514/discussion-between-highfive-and-lovesalesforce)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [apex string methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm) as following:

```
string s = 'Anything-Insert-Anything-True';

if(s.contains('-Insert-') && s.endsWith('-True')){
        system.debug('success');
}
//repeat for your other possibilities
```

Comment: No, something more generic I am looking for.

Comment: Hmm, could you then reflect that and any other conditions you have in your question by an update ? Else it's pretty hard for anyone to answer you an answer you're really looking for.